# Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android. Whenever I run app on emulator it say"Unfortunalty stopped" when I run and checked the ADT logs it says

```
05-01 15:43:26.597: E/dalvikvm-heap(1022): Out of memory on a 36864016-byte allocation.
05-01 15:43:26.687: W/dalvikvm(1022): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jaisri.myapp/com.jaisri.myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:807)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at com.jaisri.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     ... 11 more
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     ... 26 more
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:431)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
05-01 15:43:26.817: E/AndroidRuntime(1022):     ... 29 more
05-01 15:45:58.767: W/lenght(1085): 1
05-01 15:46:03.977: E/dalvikvm-heap(1085): Out of memory on a 36864016-byte allocation.
05-01 15:46:04.237: W/dalvikvm(1085): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jaisri.myapp/com.jaisri.myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:807)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at com.jaisri.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     ... 11 more
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     ... 26 more
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:431)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
05-01 15:46:04.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     ... 29 more
05-01 15:46:21.367: E/Trace(1130): error opening trace file: No such file or directory
```

Please help me . wher should I check the problem. I am not getting it.

Here is the xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF5D00" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/jkheading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/jkhead" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/jkheadingtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/search"
            android:src="@drawable/header" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/jksearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/jkhead" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/jkedit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/search1"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/search1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/jksearch" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/jkrunn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/jkheading"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="#FFAF00" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jkruntext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/jkrunn1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/jkrunn"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="#FFAF00" >

        <com.jaisri.jklinks.Scrolltext
            android:id="@+id/jkruntext1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
        </com.jaisri.jklinks.Scrolltext>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/jkheading"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/firstlayout"
            layout="@layout/flip9" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/listlayout"
            layout="@layout/flip8" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/listlayout1"
            layout="@layout/flip7" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/listlayout2"
            layout="@layout/flip6" />
    </ViewFlipper>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/jkfooter"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/jkrunn1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/glasseffect" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/face" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/jklike"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/like" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/register"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/login2" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/register1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/jkheading"
        android:background="@drawable/jklogin" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Username" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/signinusername"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/signinpassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/signinusername"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/jksignin"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/signinpassword"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/iconback"
            android:text="Enter"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/signinusername"
            android:text="Password" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signup"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/jksignin"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/jksignin"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
            android:background="@drawable/iconback"
            android:text="  Signup  "
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/close"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/signup"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/signup"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
            android:background="@drawable/iconback"
            android:text="Exit"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
     />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/register2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/jkheading"
        android:background="@drawable/jklogin" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:text="Email-id" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/signupemail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/signupusername"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/signupemail"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/signupemail"
            android:text="Username" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/signupusername"
            android:text="Password" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/signuppassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/signupusername"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/signuppassword"
            android:text="Confirm Password" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/signuppassword2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/signuppassword"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Jksignup"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/signuppassword2"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:background="@drawable/iconback"
            android:text=" Sign Up "
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/close1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/signuppassword2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:background="@drawable/iconback"
            android:text="Exit"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/jkfooter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/jkfoot" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jkadv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Your Ad Image Here "
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/slide"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/sideopen" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/slide1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/slider"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/sideclose" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks alot

Comment: It looks like your `layout` file has something wrong with it. Post the `layout` xml you are trying to `inflate`

Comment: @codeMagic in layout I have many XML . I dont know which one I should see. :(

Comment: Your `layout` should be your xml file then you have `views` inside of that. Do you call `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`? If so, I would start with that xml if it crashes as soon as trying to open it

Comment: @codeMagic I have posted the XML above . In Java code it says   setContentView(R.layout.activity); So I have posted activity.xml

Comment: This may be the culprit `<com.jaisri.jklinks.Scrolltext
            android:id="@+id/jkruntext1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
        </com.jaisri.jklinks.Scrolltext>`

Comment: I would start by taking that out and see if it fixes it then we know where to start

Comment: I removed that and now it says be 05-01 16:23:08.838: W/dalvikvm(1735): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-01 16:23:08.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1735): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 16:23:08.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1735): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jaisri.jklinks/com.jaisri.jklinks.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 16:23:08.867: E/AndroidRuntime(1735):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)

Comment: Probably because you are attempting to access that class and now it isn't there. Can you post that custom `ScrollView` class?

Comment: @codeMagic its here http://pastebin.com/wEDWTu4J

Comment: I think because your package name in that class doesn't match what's in the xml, but not positive

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you examine the `Caused by:` lines, it looks like the root cause is an `OutOfMemoryError` that's occurring in `BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset()`. (Note also the references to "Out of memory on a 36864016-byte allocation").

Are you trying to include a very large image file in your layout somewhere?

Comment: yes I think so .. Is that the problem . The same app is installed on my Sansung Note10.1 but not in sony xperia

Comment: I just checked I am importing my background image and its size is 256kb and its the largest image in my app. Is this is problem

Comment: I have compressed the image and I am not getting the Out of memory now but rest error is same as before.

Comment: Yes, The problem is background image size and resolution

Answer (score 6):

Just for future people having this issue you can add in manifest:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

this fixed the issue for me.

Comment: this increases the heap size, if the crash is due to a leak it's better to fix the problem than to delay it.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that your xml class definition doesn't match the package you have in your custom class. Assuming it is correct in your class, try changing the xml to

```
 <com.jaisri.myapp.Scrolltext
        android:id="@+id/jkruntext1"
```

I haven't used custom `Views` much but I'm pretty sure this is a problem. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @codeMagic . I have changed the package name intentonally before posting here . Anyway I have found the problem. The problem is backjround image size and resolution. When I reduced its resolution and size, it showed me another error but that is genuine one. Thanka alot.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting same error for api 5 and 6. Found out that I was using some `some.xml` which located under the folder `drawable-24`. So after click-dropping the `come.xml` to `drawable` happy days error gone. Project -> app -> res -> (check the drawable-24 `find usages`)